Reflection and Transmission Coefficients in Electromagnetic Waves in a Metal with Dispersion
Imagine a plane wave coming from vacuum hitting a half-space with dielectric dispersion ($\omega$) perpendicularly. We characterize the incident wave as follows: Orienting the wave in the z-direction, we have an electric field
$$\mathbf{E}_I = E_{0_I}e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\mathbf{\hat{x}}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_I = \frac{1}{c}E_{0_I}e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\mathbf{\hat{y}}$$
Hence the wave is polarized in the x-direction. We have the boundary conditions: $D_\perp,B_\perp,D_\parallel ,H_\parallel$ being continuous, hence skipping the straight-forward calculations, I get that the reflection coefficient and transmission coefficient are:
$$R \equiv \frac{I_R}{I_I} = \left(\frac{\mu_2 - \mu n_2}{\mu_2+\mu n_2}\right)^2 $$
$$T \equiv \frac{I_T}{I_I} = \left(n_2\mu_0 c^2\right)\left(\frac{2\mu_2}{\mu_2+\mu n_2}\right)^2$$
(If I need to expand on my calculations, please let me know). Now, consider a metal as a dielectric medium with dispersion $$\epsilon(\omega)=\epsilon_0 + \frac{i\epsilon_0\sigma_0}{\omega}$$ How do the reflection and transmission coefficients behave in the limiting case of low frequencies? How do the calculations change when we're discussing conductors as dielectric mediums? Any help is much appreciated, most textbooks only consider the Ohm law dispersion relation, which I can't seem to relate to the frequency dependent dispersion.

For low frequencies (in Gaussian units),
${\bf B}=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi\sigma}{\omega}}e^{i\pi/4}{\bf{\hat k}\times E}$.
Put this into the usual derivation of R, which should be close to 1.
There's no point in calculating T because the attenuation is so fast.
A complete, somewhat complicated, discussion is at the start of chapter 11 of my EM textbook.

Thanks for the answer. I will check your book, nonetheless could you elaborate how you deducted B, in difference to B for regular plane waves on non-conducting media. Should I write the permittivity as a function of the conductivity and then continue, I'm not quite getting how the permittivity (in this form, as the imaginary part of the conductivity) is being used to get that B?
